# Как подсчитать количество значений по условию в скользящем окне?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, анализ-данных, обработка-данных

Есть столбец: `D['W'] = [1,1,1,1,1,9,8,1,1,1,1,1,1]`

На выходе хочу получить колонку с к-вом элементов в столбце 'W' из последних 4, которые > 7 `D['Col W>20 on 7'] = [0,0,0,0,0,1,2,2,2,1,0,0,0]`

Как подсчитать в скользящем окне количество элементов из последних 4, которые >7?

Так, разумеется не работает:

```
D['Col W>20 on 7'] = len(D['W'].rolling(4)>7)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Попробуйте так:

```
s = pd.Series([1,1,1,1,1,9,8,1,1,1,1,1,1])

res = s.rolling(4, min_periods=1).apply(lambda x: x.gt(7).sum())
```

результат:

```
In [137]: res
Out[137]: 
0     0.0
1     0.0
2     0.0
3     0.0
4     0.0
5     1.0
6     2.0
7     2.0
8     2.0
9     1.0
10    0.0
11    0.0
12    0.0
dtype: float64
```

Comment: забыла указать python 2.7. Подскажите, откуда импортировать gt? в math не нашла

Comment: @АннаЛебедева, его импортировать не надо - [это метод pandas.Series](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.gt.html). Вы пробовали запустить код из ответа, не меняя его?

Comment: python при запуске приведенного вами кода выдает :C:\ProgramData\Anaconda2\lib\site-packages\ipykernel_launcher.py:3: FutureWarning: Currently, 'apply' passes the values as ndarrays to the applied function. In the future, this will change to passing it as Series objects. You need to specify 'raw=True' to keep the current behaviour, and you can pass 'raw=False' to silence this warning
  This is separate from the ipykernel package so we can avoid doing imports until
После: AttributeError: 'numpy.ndarray' object has no attribute 'gt'

Comment: @АннаЛебедева, у вас устаревшая версия Pandas. В первом предупреждении уже указан правильный путь - надо добавить параметр raw=False в вызов “.apply()”